# split using boost::is_any_of confuses over delimeter ",," and ","

Tags: c++, boost

I currently have a string that has the following structure

```
xxx,xxx,xxxxxxx,,xxxxxx,xxxx
```

Now I am using the following code

```
 std::vector< std::string > vct;
 boost::split( vct, str, boost::is_any_of(",,") );
```

Now the boost splits up the string once it finds "," and not ",," which I dont want. Is there any way that I could explicitly specify that it should split only if it finds ",," and not ","

Comment: The whole point of `is_any_of` is to represent any one of the characters in the string you provide. If that's not what you want, then don't use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`is_any_of(",,")` will match anything that's specified in the list. In this case either `,` or `,`

What you are looking for is along the line of

```
boost::algorithm::split_regex( vct, str, regex( ",," ) ) ;
```

Comment: I think you got it backwards: it matches `,` or `,`, not `,` or `,`.

Answer (score 3):

For future reference..

boost::split takes a 4th parameter `eCompress` that can lets you treat adjacent separators as a single separator:

> **eCompress**
>
> If eCompress argument is set to token_compress_on, adjacent
>   separators are merged together. Otherwise, every two separators
>   delimit a token.

All you have to do is specify the parameter. You can skip the second `,` too, as:

```
boost::split( vct, str, boost::is_any_of(","),
              boost::algorithm::token_compress_on)
```

[Here's the documentation.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/split_idp58609016.html)

Answer (score 0):

Is_any_of splits on any of the characters in the string. It will not do what you want. You need to look in the boost manual for another predicate.

Edit: Out of curiosity I went looking in the API myself, infortunantly I could not find a ready predicate for what you want. Worst case you hasve to write it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <functional>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/compare.hpp>
...

std::vector< std::string > vct;
//boost::split( vct, str, [](const auto& arg) { return arg == str::string(",,"); } );
boost::split( vct, str, std::bind2nd(boost::is_equal, std::string(",,")) );
```